# Rails console wrap commands with block automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We're using the audited gem to track changes to models, but we also want to track if the change was done via the Rails console. Currently any changes done this way will just have `nil` for the `user_id`. But changes done via the code and background jobs will also be marked as `nil`, so its possible to differentiate between the two.

According to the docs, you can specify a user before any code is run: https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited#custom-audit-user

```
Audited.audit_class.as_user("console-user-#{ENV['SSH_USER']}") do
  # any commands run here will be treated as `console-user-username`
end
```

However we don't want to have to manually wrap any update commands we run on the console to make sure they're recorded as such. Is it possible to automatically have almost some sort of middleware that will wrap all console commands with that block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gem also provides

```rb
Audited.store[:audited_user] = "username"
```

as an option to store the user, not just `.as_user`. This one is easier to use since it doesn't take a block.

Put this code into your `.irbrc` or `.pryrc` file and it will be run every time the console is started.

Alternatively it can be added to an initializer in your project and use `defined?(Rails::Console)` to see if the console is being initialized or the app.

Comment: I've posted the direction I went with using an initializer above for others that might want to do something similar and see a full end to end example. Thanks for the answer, been really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

For those that want to see what I ultimately used (Thanks to Slim Liiser for the answer which helped massively: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76637170/302533).

I added an initializer at: `~/config/initializers/audited.rb`

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

whoami = ENV.fetch('USER', nil)
username = 'Rails console'
username += " - #{whoami}" if whoami.present?

Audited.store[:audited_user] = username if defined? Rails::Console
```

This gets the current logged in user on the machine itself and who is running Rails console and then if present (which in all likelihood it will be) it will append it to the Rails console string so we can identify the user when doing console commands. Works perfectly!